# Chrome opens a second Transmission window with magnet links. How does it check if there is a transmission open or not?

Tags: chrome, mime-types, bittorrent, xdg-open, transmission

The magnet link is correctly set with `xdg-mime` to open in `transmission`, and also in `.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`.

If `transmission` is NOT running, everything works as expected (click a magnet link or torrent file, and it opens).

If `transmission` is running, clicking on a magnet link in chrome will open a second transmission window.

This does not occur neither in firefox nor with the command `xdg-open "magnet-link"`. The problems seems to be only in chrome.

Tech specs:

```
Debian buster with 4.19.0-2-amd64, fully upgraded.
transmission-gtk 2.94 (d8e60ee44f)
google chrome Version 72.0.3626.81 (Official Build) (64-bit)
xdg-open 1.1.3
awesome WM v4.3
```

edit: Checking chrome's log, I can see this related line

```
[21407:21407:0207/152959.142127:VERBOSE1:navigator_impl.cc(111)] Failed Provisional Load: magnet:?xt=urn:btih:<magnet_url_with_trackers-hidden_for_privacy>, error_code: -3, error_description: The webpage at <strong jscontent="failedUrl"></strong> might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address., showing_repost_interstitial: 0, frame_id: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite late but for anyone arriving here with the same issue: I discovered this is happenning due to chrome/chromium changing environment variables.

In my case chromuim set `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=disabled:`

I fixed it by adding `unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` right after the `#!/bin/sh` in the start of `/usr/bin/xdg-open`

You can use this command:

```
sudo sed -i 's:#!/bin/sh:#!/bin/sh\nunset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS:' /usr/bin/xdg-open
```

Note you'll have to run it again every time package xdg-util being updated.